# Laravel search where relationship does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I can query where relationships exist by using the whereHas method, but now I need to get the inverse of this result, where the result does not match the result in the whereHas clause.

Here's my query:

```
$query->whereHas('actions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('actions.created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->addDays(-30));
});
```

This gets things that are actioned in the last 30 days, but I need to get the things that are NOT actioned in the last 30 days.

It seems like I need to get the max(actions.created_at) from the relationship and see if that value is > 30 days ago, but I'm not sure how I can do this with eloquent.

Note: the relationship between person and action is 1 to many, so there could be multiple action records linked, so I can't just flip the operator to be a "<="

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember `whereHas` *has* more than two parameters:

```
$query->whereHas('actions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('actions.created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->addDays(-30));
}, '=',0);
```

As a matter of fact, it has two more, but by default it is set to '>=' and  '1'. So we add the parameters '=' and '0' (or '<', and '1' for what it matters) to convert it in a subquery like 'all the actions that are not in the subset of actions added in less than 30 days).

`whereHas` method: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas

Comment: Ah! thanks for that, didn't realise there were extra parameters as there were no example of it in the docs.

Comment: awesome solution

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change your where query to a smaller or equal than?

```
$query->whereHas('actions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('actions.created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->addDays(-30));
});
```

Comment: This won't work because the relationship between person and action is 1 to many. Which means this would return persons who had an action created <= 30 days ago, but that person could also have an action created > 30 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Pseudo Code]:

```
$actions = App\Models\Action::all();
foreach($actions as $actionArray){
    $actionCreatedAt = new Carbon($actionArray->created_at);
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $difference = $actionCreatedAt->diff($now)->days;
    if($difference>30){
       $exceedingThirty[] = $actionArray;
    } else {
       continue;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `$exceedingThirty` array, in your view.

**OR**

Try this:

```
$sql = "DATEDIFF(actions.created_at, '".date('Y-m-d')."' ) > ". 30;
return App\Models\Action::whereRaw( $sql )->get();
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I know I could use a loop, but I was trying to avoid using a loop if possible.